# Public IP address does not work in internal network

Tags: nat, network, firewall, port-forwarding

I have configured port forwarding to my system from the router configuration menu, when I try to access the public IP address in the internal network it does not respond but it is accessible outside of the router network such as mobile data.

Refer to the configurations of my router as below;

[image: router configurations]

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the public IP address, source NATing internal clients, forwarding the public IP back to a private one (destination NAT) and everything in reverse for a reply is highly inefficient. This "hairpinning" is very often deactivated on a router by default, some routers even don't support it at all.

Instead, make sure your private IP clients access the server's private IP. The easiest way is to use split-brain DNS on your DNS server (details are off-topic here). Not only does this remove load from the router (hairpinning is often done in software) but it's also much faster, enabling your clients to utilize the server's full bandwidth over a switched connection.